# Adding custom styles to CKEditor

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I recently added CKEditor to my app and I would like to include my own CSS stylesheets within the editor so that I can select them within the editor.

How do I accomplish this? My code so far looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',{
        uiColor : '#9AB8F3',
    });

</script>
```

Comment: You can add custom styles to an editor quite easily. [This page](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles) shows how.

Comment: Please select the correct answer as the currently selected answer suggests that another answer is better.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

**Please look at @metavida answer for a better answer than this**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',{

          uiColor : '#9AB8F3',
          stylesSet.add('default', [
               { name: 'My Custom Block', element: 'h3', styles: { color: 'Blue'} },
               { name: 'My Custom inline style', element: 'q'}
          ]);    
    });

</script>
```

Though if you're using this in more than one place it'd be best to look at putting this into the stylescombo\styles\default.js  file and updating your config.js file accordingly as per api.

Comment: But this isn't even valid JS!

Comment: @Matti what isn't specifically?

Comment: Your method call sitting in the middle of an object literal isn't valid.

Comment: I just added an answer that breaks the `CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add` and `stylesSet` option into separate calls. I've used a variation of the code in my answer on my own website.

Comment: to all those downvoters, I can't delete this as it is the accepted answer!

Answer (score 45):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // This code could (may be should) go in your config.js file
  CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('my_custom_style', [
    { name: 'My Custom Block', element: 'h3', styles: { color: 'blue'} },
    { name: 'My Custom Inline', element: 'span', attributes: {'class': 'mine'} }
  ]);
  // This code is for when you start up a CKEditor instance
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',{
    uiColor: '#9AB8F3',
    stylesSet: 'my_custom_style'
  });
</script>
```

You can also read the full documentation of the `stylesSet.add` syntax:

- [CKEditor 4 documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.stylesSet)
- [CKEditor 3 documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles), as Vincent mentioned.
- [CKEditor 4 How Do I Customize the Styles Drop-Down List?](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_styles)
- [CKEditor 3 How Do I Customize the Styles Drop-Down List?](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Styles_List_Customization)

Comment: hey op - select this answer.

Comment: The best way is actually to use this: http://ckeditor.com/addon/stylesheetparser see my answer below.

Comment: I disagree, this way @joshua.paling you pull through every selector in the css file, which means creating a dedicated file for this purpose.

Answer (score 18):

This works for me

```
CKEDITOR.addCss('body{background:blue;}');
```

Comment: This function should be called **before** the creation of editor instances (from [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-addCss)).

Comment: Such a nice, simple answer.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed

Answer (score 8):

As has already been mentioned, there is a page explaining how to set up a set of [custom styles](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles). What the little gem hidden on that page (and not really clear) is that rather than creating a named set of styles, you can define the styles inline in your configuration, like this:

```
    stylesSet : [
    {
        name : 'Green Title',
        element : 'h3',
        styles :
        {
            'color' : 'Green'
        }
    } ],
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to use this plugin: http://ckeditor.com/addon/stylesheetparser

Paste it inside the 'ckeditor/plugins' directory, then include something like this in your 'ckeditor/config.js':

```
config.extraPlugins = 'stylesheetparser';
config.contentsCss = '/css/inline-text-styles.css';
config.stylesSet = [];
```

Where '/css/inline-text-styles.css' is a path to your own css folder in your webroot, outside of ckeditor. That saves you having to mix css with javascript.

Comment: This seems like it could be helpful, but you say "your own css folder" and then show a path to a file.  Does the path depend on the location of the ckeditor itself, or it always is from root?  I can't get it to work and I think it is the path.

Answer (score 5):

Little late to the party here, but the default styles are in `_source/plugins/styles/styles/default.js`. You could use that as your style config and add styles and it would effectively be appending.