# CKEditor -- How can I add document-specific CSS styles

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor to allow editing of template-based HTML newsletters with inline CSS. Each newsletter may have unique CSS styles to be applied to it.

How can add the document-specific styles to the Styles selection menu in the editor? I know I refer to a CSS file, but such file does not exist, as the styles are in the edited document.

Comment: does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to add more options to the styles then you need to edit the following file

```
ckeditor/plugins/styles/styles/default.js
```

**OR**

see the documentation for doing so here http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles

**OR**

see this being discussed on SO here [Adding custom styles to CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102797/adding-custom-styles-to-ckeditor)

Comment: Yes, the second link was useful. The styles are document-specific, so I'll have to convert them to json on the back end and insert them into the page loading the CKEditor instance. Wish there was a way to add the styles as pure CSS...